# NextJS: Next Build Typescript Not Installed

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to build my `NextJS` application which coded in typescript. In my local computer it is working fine. I can just call `next build` and it works fine. In my hosting server, it gives me this error:

```
> next build

It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.

Please install typescript by running:

npm install --save-dev typescript

If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).
```

I have tried to install typescript with: `npm install --save-dev typescript` also `npm -g typescript` but it is still giving me the same error.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "generateDBModel": "prisma generate",
    "migrateDB": "prisma migrate dev",
    "syncDB": "npm run generateDBModel && npm run migrateDB",
    "generate-capacitor-config": "node ./generate_capacitor_config.js",
    "build-mobile": "set NODE_ENV=production && npm run generate-capacitor-config && next build && next export && npx cap sync && npx cap open android",
    "android": "set NODE_ENV=development && npm run generate-capacitor-config && npx cap sync && npx cap open android && npm run dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.5.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.5.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.14.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/ftp": "^0.3.33",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^10.1.0",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
    "@uiw/react-md-editor": "^3.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "ftp": "^0.3.10",
    "highlight.js": "^11.5.1",
    "ip": "^1.1.8",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "next-remove-imports": "^1.0.6",
    "node-html-parser": "^5.3.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.51.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.5.1",
    "@types/node": "17.0.34",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.4",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "prisma": "^3.14.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
...
```

Both server and my local computer are using `Node 16.15.1`. The server is using `pm2` to run the script (I tried to run it manually from SSH, but this error is there).

I do not know what causes this because typescript is installed. Please help someone?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that typescript is installed as a dev dependency, which wouldn't be installed in a production environment.

Inside of your package.json, move `"typescript": "4.6.4",` from devDependencies --> dependencies.